# Flash memory pq1 8GB only showing You need to format when connected to my computer

Tags: memory, flash, format

When connect my PQ1 8GB Flash memory to computer or tablet a massage apear that says needs to be formatted .

I tried to solve this with this solution (but it didn't work) :

in "run"-> type Chkdsk F: /r (F: is my flash drive)

My data in flash memory isn't important. Please help me.

Comment: If your data is not important means format it.

Answer (score 0):

Use diskpart to format the USB.

Method:

> 1. Insert USB
> 2. Open Command Prompt
> 3. Type 'diskpart' without quotes and press Enter.
> 4. A new cmd window will open, type 'list disk' and recognize the USB Drive Name.
> 5. Now type 'select disk x', where X is the drive number or drive letter of the USB flash drive, and then click ENTER.
> 6. Type 'clean', and the click ENTER. This command deletes all data from the USB flash drive.